# Setting visible(false) of icon

Tags: java, swing

I used this to assign each icon to a button

```
  for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++)
buttons[i].setIcon( iconList.get(i) );
```

How can I set something like visible(false) of this icon after some time?

Comment: read about timers  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html

Comment: When you want to make button invisible, you can use `button[i].setVisible(false)`. If you want to delete Icon: `button[i].setIcon(null)`